# Select the last record in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, greatest-n-per-group

There is a table `Remark` that contains data as shown below:

```
       SerialNo | RemarkNo  | Desp
=============================================
             10 |         1 | rainy
             10 |         2 | sunny
             11 |         1 | sunny
             11 |         2 | rainy
             11 |         3 | cloudy
             12 |         1 | rainy
```

If I run a query `SELECT * FROM remark WHERE remark_no IN (SELECT MAX(remark_no) FROM remark GROUP BY serial_no);`, I still get the above result:

What query will return the following result:

```
             10 |         2 | sunny
             11 |         3 | cloudy
             12 |         1 | rainy
```

That is, the last record in each group should be returned??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  r1.*
FROM remark r1
  LEFT JOIN remark r2
    ON (r1.serial_no = r2.serial_no
    AND r1.remark_no < r2.remark_no)
WHERE r2.remark_no IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the top RemarkNo for each SerialNo (along with the other fields from the same row) :
Select all records where there isn't a higher RemarkNo for the same SerialNo

```
SELECT *
FROM remark r1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT SerialNo FROM remark r2
   WHERE (r2.RemarkNo>r1.RemarkNo)
     AND (r2.SerialNo=r1.SerialNo)
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da1b/21

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by returning your results and using a sort order. For example...

```
SELECT * from GROUP Order By GROUP.ID DESC
```

This will return results in the order of last record first. Then if you do not loop through results you will return only one record... the last one recorded.

Comment: Ever wondered what can slow down the performance of database results the most? It is joined tables.